# Android Bluetooth Adapter scan mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I would like to understand what causes Android `BluetoothAdapter` to change its scan mode automatically without any user intervention? I registered a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the changes in scan mode. Initially it was in the `SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE`, then after a while (a minute or so) it became `SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE`.

Are there any system events that cause such changes?

Answer (score 0):

The Android system automatically changes Bluetooth back to non-discoverable after the timeout displayed in the system activity that requests permission to make the device discoverable.

The default timeout is 120 seconds. If needed, your app can request a longer timeout using BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION. This timeout can be up to 3600 seconds. Here's an example from the [Bluetooth documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) requesting a 5 minute timeout:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```